# How to design a database for non-time invariant data

Tags: database-design

I am looking at designing a database where entries will probably not be time-invariant. For example, it contain entries of a customer company. The problem with a customer company is that many things can happen to it. The company can split, merge, move, go bankrupt, be bought, buy another company and so on. If I want to track interaction with this company over time, how should I design the database to be robust against all these things? I will also most probably have people in the database. These are also volatile - they resign, change job and so on.

So what is the best practice for working with non-time invariant data in a relational database? Or should I use some other database scheme?

Comment: For example, you can store data with additional Validity field. Data is altered never, if you need to alter data you set Validity as False to existing record(s) and insert the actual one with Validity as True. In common you work only with valid records. And partitioning by this field value may be safe.

Comment: You might need to track the changes, and store them in "audit" or "history" tables. In SQL Server this can be done by using Triggers or temporal tables. Tracking these changes is I/O intensive however.

Comment: Read about slowly changing dimensions.

Comment: You might take a look on Party-Role-Relationship model, and, in general on Len Silverston's  Universal Data Model books. Briefly, companies (organizations), as well as people have different type of relationships between them and play different roles .  Each of the relationship and role is temporal (like in real world), and can have "date from" and "date through"  attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem easily solved by placing key tables in version normal form (VNF). This is actually just a flavor of 2nf but done in a way that provides the ability to query current data and past data using the same query.

A datetime parameter is used to provide the distinction. When the value is set to NOW, the current data is returned. When the value is set to a specific datetime value in the past, the data that was current at that date and time is returned.

A brief discussion of the particulars can be found in an answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505253/3658753). That answer also contains links to more information if you think it is something that would work for you.